# nhibernate linq magic, display everything except one record

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm retrieving 5 records from my db using nhibernate linq like this

```
private IList<News> GetNews()
{        
    List<News> data = new List<News>();
    using (session..)
    {
       using (transaction...)
       {
           data = s.Query<News>().Take(5).ToList();
           transaction.Commit();
       }
    }
    return data;
}
```

If I'm displaying last record from GetNews() how can I select rest 4 except last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Skip(1).Take(4)
```